# Writing to a text file from a TFDMemTable

Tags: excel, delphi, text, fdmemtable

I need to write the contents of a `TFDMemTable` to a text file for later import into Excel. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Write the data into a CSV file, then load that into Excel.

Comment: Don't you want to direct data export to Excel (using ODBC driver)? If not, then what @MartynA suggests is the way (you can use `TFDBatchMove` with `TFDBatchMoveTextWriter`).

Comment: `TFDMemTable.SaveToFile()` can save to XML or JSON format. Excel can import XML, and there are 3rd party JSON-to-CSV converters available. Otherwise, you will have to loop through the table records manually writing each record to a file in whatever format you want, such as with a `TStreamWriter`

Comment: @Remy, you don't have to do those extra steps. FireDAC has optimized use for exports implemented in the `TFDBatchMove` component.

Comment: So im using the TKBMCSVSTREAMFORMAT  and I get an error on this line:
          Inventory.mInventoryCount.SaveToFile('Inventory'); How do i specify the file type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With FireDAC, you can use the [**TFDBatchMove**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.BatchMove.TFDBatchMove) component with [**TFDBatchMoveDataSetReader**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.BatchMove.DataSet.TFDBatchMoveDataSetReader) as [**Reader**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.BatchMove.TFDBatchMove.Reader) and [**TFDBatchMoveTextWriter**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.BatchMove.Text.TFDBatchMoveTextWriter) as [**Writer**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.BatchMove.TFDBatchMove.Writer). So as you can copy data to Excel DBMS by using ODBC driver with the mentioned component.

The [**TFDBatchMove**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.BatchMove.TFDBatchMove) component is optimized for performance and I would personally recommend its use whenever you need to copy data from one data source to another including this case since you can specify format, field mappings and others in a flexible way.

Comment: So I have had some success, I found out where the access violation is coming from, for some reason if use the third party memtable component everything reads and writes fine to a .csv file. If i use the TFDMemtable component for some reason it is unable to access it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's impossible for me to help without knowing what's happening (or knowing your code) :-) Just debug your application, let the access violation exception raise and inspect the call stack to find the source of the problem.